# putting a key in json in a specific directory put the key in all directory (JsonPath.parse(String).put)

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

I have a json template which looks like this.

```
         {
        "parent": {
            "dir1": {
                "key11": {
                    "min": 1,
                    "max": 100
                },
                "key12": {
                    "sample1": "txt",
                    "sample2": "100.25"
                }
            },
            "dir2": {
                "key21": {
                    "min": 1,
                    "max": 100
                },
                "key22": {
                    "sample1": "USD",
                    "sample2": "100.25"
                }
            }
        }
     }
```

In this I have a logic to parse the json and check (while iterating) if parent.dir1 has some specific key for e.g. "goldenKey".
If key is not found then put() the "key (goldenKey)" in jsonpath
JsonPath.parse(jsonString).put(jsonpath, key, value).json();

To get the jsonPath where to put key I am going back one node by splitting current jsonPath by "." from last and convert it to key which needs be to put.
like below code

```
try {
//set jsonpath, if key not found then catch
JsonPath.parse(json).set("$.parent.dir1.goldenKey", "golden").json();
} catch (final PathNotFoundException e) {
//json path of the key
String jsonpath = "$.parent.dir1.goldenKey";
//get the key by getting last index of "."
final String key = jsonpath.substring(jsonpath.lastIndexOf(".") +1);
jsonpath = jsonpath.substring(0, jsonpath.lastIndexOf("."));
JsonPath.parse(json).put(jsonpath, "goldenKey", "golden").json();}
```

Issue is that, instead of putting the key, value on the given json path (i.e. dir1 in this code) it put the key and value in both dir1 and dir23

Please let me know if the explanation is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the substring from the hard coded jsonpath. jsonpath should be `$.parent.dir1` when adding the value `"goldenKey":"golden"`. This should add the key value pair under dir1 alone. Double check it once.

Comment: Hi Petter thanks for taking time to look into my issue. 
My guess for what you are referring is on this line :

`String jsonpath = "$.parent.dir1.goldenKey";`

It is actually a method like **giveMeAJsonPathForGivenField(String field)**, so jsonPaths are predefined in some other class. so I have to play with that jsonpath value _($.parent.dir1.goldenKey)_ to get the key(goldenKey) and jsonpath where i have to put it _($.parent.dir1)_

In line 
`jsonpath = jsonpath.substring(0, jsonpath.lastIndexOf("."));`

jsonpath has the correct value : "$.parent.dir1"